# Style tag seems to be in the wrong order when updating to material-ui v5

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using material-ui for my next.js program and trying to update it from v4 to v5. I switch the sytle engine to styled-component for I've already been using it in my project before.
After updating, I found some components such as MenuItem got broken style. [(style tags in html head)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTipk.png) I looked into the chrome console and it seems like the style tag is not in correct order. [(styles override in wrong order)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1tb.png) As you can see in the screenshot, some Mui jss style tags are inserted after the styled-component style tag, which makes styles overriding each other in wrong order. I have no idea about where those jss style tags comes from and how to change the order. I found something in the doc of material-ui about css injection order but seems like it doesn't relate to this kind of situation. Any one help?